# net/ssh in ruby(how to find)

Tags: ruby

my question is how do i fing net/ssh file in ruby . i am using 1.8.4 version of ruby

Answer (score 0):

Described [here](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2008/5/2/net-ssh-2-0-and-friends). Basically:

```
$ gem install net-ssh
```

and in your ruby code:

```
require 'net/ssh'
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether that will work. The OP is using Ruby 1.8.4 which has been obsolete for ages. I'm pretty sure the latest version of `net/ssh` doesn't work on 1.8.4.

Comment: what i want to know is whether net/ssh come with ruby 1.8.4